# Divs layout similar to grid

Tags: html, css

So I have html layout as this one:

```
<h1>Title</h1>
<div class="info">Extra info</div>
<img src="image.jpg" />
<div class="summary">Short summary</div>
```

How to display it as:

```
<img src="image.jpg" /> <h1>Title</h1>
                        <div class="info">Extra info</div>
                        <div class="summary">Short summary</div>
```

I tried with floats however it displayed as:

```
                        <h1>Title</h1>
<img src="image.jpg" /> <div class="info">Extra info</div>
                        <div class="summary">Short summary</div>
```

I tried with positions (relative and absolute) and I got what I wanted, unfortunately it doesn't work very well in IE and if the short summary text is very short then image hides behind the other elements. I don't know image height (dynamic height), so height: xxx px; doesn't fit here.

Any help would be great.

**EDIT:**
I can't div wrap all (right side) elements in this case.

Comment: Posting the CSS would help give us an idea of what you may have done wrong/missed.

Comment: @KevinBrydon, floats version - http://jsfiddle.net/EJ4Zq/9 ; positions version - http://jsfiddle.net/EJ4Zq/7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get it done without adding additional divs to your code, add the below CSS

```
img{float:left}
div{display:table-row}
```

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/EJ4Zq/3/)**

---

Use `position:absolute`

```
<h1>Title</h1>
  <div class="info">Extra info</div>
 <img src="image.jpg" width="40" />
   <div class="summary">Short summary</div>
```

**CSS**

```
img{float:left; top:0; position:absolute; left:0}
div, h1{display:block; margin-left:40px /*Add image width value as margin-left*/ }
```

**[DEMO 3](http://jsfiddle.net/EJ4Zq/6/)**

Comment: DEMO 2 is very close, but what if I can't change the order of html elements? It must be <h1><div><img><div>

Comment: Sowmya, as I said in my first post "I tried with positions (relative and absolute) and I got what I wanted, unfortunately it doesn't work very well in IE and if the short summary text is very short then image hides behind the other elements."
I updated your DEMO 3 - http://jsfiddle.net/EJ4Zq/7/
Images overlapping.

Comment: I also updated your DEMO 2 to my case and it's so close - http://jsfiddle.net/EJ4Zq/9/ , however summary dropped to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="image.jpg" class="left-image" />
<div class="right-col">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <div class="info">Extra info</div>
    <div class="summary">Short summary</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.left-image {
    float: left;
}
.right-col {
    margin-left: <width-of-image> px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, div wrapping around all (right side) elements is a good solution, however it's not possible to wrap them in this case.

Answer (score 0):

how about this: http://jsfiddle.net/xpq2m/

CSS

```
body {
    padding-left: 100px;
}
img#s { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: I already tried it but if the summary text is very short then image hides behind the other elements.